# Point of using the AWS Cognito Identity

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Is the point of using the following code so that I can access other AWS tools directly with my ios app?

```
    AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[DeveloperAuthenticationProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"poolId"];

    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

    __block NSString *cognitoId = nil;

    // Retrieve your Amazon Cognito ID
    [[credentialsProvider getIdentityId] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task)
    {
        if (task.error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // the task result will contain the identity id
            cognitoId = task.result;
        }

        return nil;
    }];
```

I then use AWS Lambda with an API gateway to get user identities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cognito is required in order to provide an execution context (authentication) when accessing an AWS resource.  What that means, is that nothing is truly anonymous on AWS - even if you don't have your users "log in", they still have a unique identifier associated with their device.

What this means is that some random person outside of your app cannot simply hit your AWS resources (S3, Lambda, etc) and execute code.

This also means you can, and must, assign execution permissions to your Lambda to allow your Cognito group to execute.

Another thing to note:  You do not need to use API gateway in order to execute Lambdas on iOS.  You can invoke natively.  I prefer doing it thusly - less configuration.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/lambda.html

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: IF I comment this out my gateway functions still work. So if I try to access anything outside the gateway like s3 directly it would fail. Right? Also using the gateway to access lambda so I can send things https://. Thanks.

Comment: If you can access your Gateway without Cognito, so can anyone else in the world.  You're functionality is wide open.  Now, maybe you're using this to provide a REST endpoint to serve assets from S3 to the web.  That makes sense.

Also, it's worth noting that all native AWS API calls from iOS are translated into https calls into the AWS REST API.

Comment: I was unaware of the native https: calls.  How do I make my api only to my user with the cognitoId? Thanks,